# Get value of a selected option in an label with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a select element in a form.
I try to get its value to paste it in a label located in an other part of the form.

I used that Javascript snippet :

```
<script>
  $('select[name=auteur]').change(function () {
  var auteur = ($(this).val());
  });
  console.log(auteur) // to check 
  document.getElementById("label-data-aut").innerHTML = auteur;
</script>
```

I select an option in the form, then look what happened. The problem is that  the label "label-data-aut" didn't get the value. Same thing for console.log.
When I put the "console.log" and the "documentgetElementById" inside the function, it works and the label is filled with the select option.

How can it work with both "documentgetElementById" and "console.log" put outside the function ?  Could that snippet be modified to make it work ?

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: please add your html part of this

Comment: Variable `auteur` is locally inside the `change` listener, declare it globally if you want to use it outside of the `change()` listener. However, you should put all of your code inside the `change()` listener if you want it to be executed on every select change, why you want it outside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code will run `document.getElementById("label-data-aut").innerHTML = auteur;` outside of a handler.

You could set the innerHTML in the change event handler. You could shorten your code to:

```
$('select[name="auteur"]').change(function () {
    document.getElementById("label-data-aut").innerHTML = auteur;
});
```

If the label that is going to be set is going to be composed by many other calls using document.getElementById", you might place the variable `auteur` outside of the function:

```
var auteur = "Initial value";
$('select[name="auteur"]').change(function () {
    document.getElementById("label-data-aut").innerHTML = auteur;
});
```

Comment: This is the correct way, still did not understand why he wanted the code outside the `change()` listener. Maybe he wanted a first value to be loaded on the label, in that case, calling this `$('select[name="auteur"]').change()` at document ready will trigger the event and initialize his label.

Comment: @Shidersz That might also be possible. If that is the case, then another option could be to set it directly when the initialization value is know.

Comment: Thank you. I want the code outside the change() because the label has to be composed of many "document.getElementById". So I have to get all the "document.getElementById" values outside the different functions to concat them and populate the label.

Comment: @Julien You might declare the variable outside of the function and update is with the other `document.getElementById` calls.

Comment: Ok thanks.I tried but with no results. Could you show me with a piece of code please ?

Comment: @Julien You could check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rum78a12/) and put the `auteur` variable outside of the function. Then the `document.getElementById` calls can manipulate that variable and at the final call to update the label you can take the `auteur` value.

Comment: @Julien Did that help you?

Comment: @The fourth bird Great it works and definitely yes that helped me ! Thank you very much !!